# Serum dex Error

Tags: anchor, solana-program, serum, dex, serum-market

i'm trying to do a token swap in my code through serum dex but I'm getting this error

```
Program 9xQeWvG816bUx9EPjHmaT23yvVM2ZWbrrpZb9PusVFin failed: custom program error: 0x100016b
```

Does anybody know what it means?

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky, but Serum encodes assertion errors through the lower 8 bits as the file, and the upper 16 bits as the line number. `0x100016b` isn't 32 bits and is missing the last hex character.

It's definitely something in the `state.rs` file, and then you'll need the full error code to find out which line it is.

Reference at https://github.com/project-serum/serum-dex/blob/92992b308885f5323b3f51eb1a0c899e35c62cb3/dex/src/error.rs#L120